# What is the correct answer to this diffferential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics

[Question]
When solving the differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \sqrt{(y+1)}$$

I've found two ways to express $y(x)$:

implicitly: $2\sqrt{(y + 1)} =  x + C$

or directly: $y = (x^2)/4 + (2xC)/4 + (C^2)/4 -1$

Although they look the same, these expressions result in different answers when
applying the  initial condition $y(0) =1$:

When using the implicit expression:

$$2\sqrt{(y(0) + 1)} = 0 + C
\\ 2\sqrt{(1 + 1)} = 0 + C
\\ C = 2\sqrt{2}$$

When using the direct expression:

$$y(0) = 0/4 + 0/4 + (C^2)/4 -1
\\ 2 = (C^2)/4
\\ C = \pm 2\sqrt{2}
\\ \text{since: }
C^2 = 8 \implies C = \pm \sqrt 8 $$

Thus, using the direct expression results in two answers (being a quadratic
equation), when 
using the implicit expression there's only one answer to C.

Which one is the complete answer?

[Additional information]
The solution's manual states that the answer should be:

$C = 2\sqrt 2 $ and the solution to the differential equation with initial condition is
 $2\sqrt{(y + 1)} =  x + 2\sqrt 2$. 
(notice, no minus sign before $2\sqrt 2 $)

However, I do not think this is the complete solution, as shown by the direct
expression, there 
may be another answer to the differential equation:

$C = - 2\sqrt(2)$ and the solution is: $2\sqrt{(y + 1)} =  x - 2\sqrt 2$

I do not know if the implicit expression hides one of the answers or if is there
something 
wrong with my use of the direct expression.

Comment: If we are working in the reals, the version with $\sqrt{8}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version with $\sqrt{8}$ is the only correct one. If you use $-\sqrt{8}$, you get that $\sqrt{y+1}$ is negative when $x=0$. But $\sqrt{y+1}$, by definition, is the **non-negative** number whose square is $y+1$.

**Remark:** A familiar related fact is that when we are solving an ordinary equation that involves square roots, squaring often introduces one or more *extraneous* solutions, that is, non-solutions.

Comment: OK, that's a good answer, thank you. However, I still think I'm missing somenthing conceptual. For example, I've also found two answers for the  following diff. equations (Still writing)

Answer (score 1):

Your explicit solution is
$$y=\Bigl(\frac{x+C}{2}\Bigr)^2-1\ .$$
This is equivalent to
$$x+C=\pm2\sqrt{y+1}\ ,$$
**not** $x+C=2\sqrt{y+1}$ as it is supposed to be.  And indeed, with the minus sign you can differentiate with respect to $x$ to get
$$1=-\frac1{\sqrt{y+1}}\frac{dy}{dx}\ ,$$
that is,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{y+1}\ ,$$
which is not the given DE.  So only the plus sign is correct.  This means that your explicit solution includes the correct solution and an incorrect solution too.